# Not a valid Inertia response

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

i use
inertiajs/inertia-laravel 0.6.3
Laravel 8.40

i got this respones every time i run my test and i have checked everything,

sometime i use `Assert` insted of `AssertableInertia`

if someone could point me on the right direction i would be glad

```
use Inertia\Testing\AssertableInertia;

use RefreshDatabase;

public function test_home_page_sponsors(): void
    {
        $sponsors = Sponsor::factory()->count(5)->create();

        $this->get('/')
            ->assertInertia(fn (AssertableInertia $page) => $page
            ->component('HomePage')
            ->has('sponsors.data', 5)
            ->has(
                'sponsors.data.0',
                fn (AssertableInertia $page) => $page
                    ->where('title', $sponsors[0]->title)
                    ->etc()
            ));
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `Assert` instead of `AssertableInertia`? The older documentation uses `Assert`. The documentation on testing on the website (https://inertiajs.com/testing) is very light and suggests that you should follow the old documentation for now.

Comment: yes it does not work, i don't know what i do wrong 2

Comment: I am not sure, but others have reported this issue too. Take a look at https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/292 and see if there's a 3rd party package interfering with tests.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue in my own Laravel project today. Do you have (Webpack) versioning enabled for you assets?

If this is the case, the test is failing because it cannot find the Mix manifest file. You should tell the test to ignore the Mix versioning:

```
$this->withoutMix();
```

I discovered the Mix error message by debugging the test:

```
$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
```

Hopefully this fix might work for you aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you're using Vite

```
$this->withoutVite();
```